# Android: EditText transparency change on click and text entry

Tags: android, text, input, android-edittext, transparency

How can I make an EditText (both the underline and android:hint) have a 50% transparency when there is no text inputted and it isn't clicked on, then change to 100% when it is either clicked on or has inputted text?

In addition, how can I change the color of the underline (not hint) to orange when the transparency is 100% (when it is clicked or text has been inputted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // If has focus then change the alpha to 1
                mEditText.setAlpha(1);
                // Set orange color filter
                mEditText.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 165, 0), PorterDuff
                        .Mode.SRC_IN);
            } else {
                // When focus is lost, check if some text has been entered.
                // If not then set the alpha to 0.5f (50% transparent)
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText().toString())) {
                    mEditText.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    // Clear the color filter
                    mEditText.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                }
            }
            mEditText.invalidate();
        }
    });
```